# Mentioning of firearms or cannons in Hinduism Scriptures?

Tags: scripture, weapon, war

The two  wikipedia articles says

> The earliest known depiction of [**cannon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon) appeared in Song
>   dynasty China as early as the 12th century, however solid
>   archaeological and documentary evidence of cannon do not appear until
>   the 13th century.
>
> ---
>
> The first primitive [**firearms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firearm) originated in 10th-century China
>   .

Now i am interested in mentioning of these two in Hinduism Scriptures like Purana , Itihasa etc. Of Course here  i am not expecting a kind of canon or firearms as we knew  today. The another point is  also I am here not asking about the Divya Astras which are mentioned in Ramayana or Mahabharata etc. But just  only  expecting  mention  of such a kind of weapon , whose basic principle   is same as the above two.

So my question is - Do Hinduism scripture mentions any  kind of mechanism / weapon similar to Guns , Cannons  etc.

Answer (score 4):

Firearm , Cannons and hand-Guns are mentioned in Hinduism scriptures like Ramayana And mahabharata. The word used for Cannons in scripture  is [**shataghnii  -शतघ्नी**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/shataghni)   .

> This śataghnī literally is that which can kill a thousand people, and
>   it is said to be a canon.

---

## Mentioning of canons in Ramayana.

[**Valmiki Ramayana**](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga5/bala_5_frame.htm) is mentioning about cannons deployed in city of Dasharatha in  -Book I : Bala Kanda - Sarga 5- The Youthful Majesties .

> सूत मागध संबाधाम् श्रीमतीम् अतुल प्रभाम् |
>  उच्चाट्टाल ध्वजवतीम्
>   **शतघ्नी** शत संकुलाम् ||  VR .1.5.11||
>
> suuta maagadha sambaadhaam shriimatiim atula prabhaam | ucchaaTTaala
>   dhvajavatiim **shataghnii** shata samkulaam ||
>
> She that prosperous city Ayodhya is muchly crammed with many a
>   eulogist and panegyrist, yet she is highly splendorous with many a
>   bastion, flag and hundreds of **batteries of canons**, and Dasharatha
>   dwells therein. [1-5-11]

Note that here the word  "shataghnii " is used for canons .

---

## Mentioning of Cannons and Hand Guns in Mahabharata.

Similarly Mahabharata is also describing this canon called shataghnii . It is mentioned in [**Mahabharata Adi Parva - Viduragamana Parva - Chapter 199.**](https://archive.org/stream/Mahabharata04SanskritHindiPanditRamnarayanGitaPress/Mahabharata%2001_%20Sanskrit-Hindi_Pandit%20Ramnarayan_Gita%20Press#page/n643/mode/2up)

भीमोतमहाचक्रं बृहतटटालसंवृतं |
दृढप्राकारनिर्युहं **शतघ्नीजालसंवृत्तं** ||

Here there are big giant wheels which are frightning. The slabs of the entrance gates of this city is pretty much strong. And this city is surrounded by series of Shatagni cannons .

---

And [**here**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01199.htm) is different verse  from same chapter

> तीक्ष्णाङ्कुश शतघ्नीभिर यन्त्रजालैश च शॊभितम |
>  आयसैश च महाचक्रैः
>   शुशुभे तत पुरॊत्तमम ||33||
>
> tīkṣṇāṅkuśa śataghnībhir yantrajālaiś ca śobhitam
>   āyasaiś ca
>   mahācakraiḥ śuśubhe tat purottamam

here Mahabharata is mentioning a series of mechanism which are similar to cannons.

---

Mahabharata is also mentioning about **hand cannons and hand guns**. It is mentioned in Mahabharata -[**Adi-Parva**](https://archive.org/stream/Mahabharata04SanskritHindiPanditRamnarayanGitaPress/Mahabharata%2001_%20Sanskrit-Hindi_Pandit%20Ramnarayan_Gita%20Press#page/n721/mode/2up)  - khandav Dahan Parva - Chapter 226 - Verse - 25. In the description of war between Devas and Krishna-Arjuna during Khandav Dahana episode.

> अय:कणपचक्राश्म भुषुण्डयुद्यतवावह: | 
> कृष्णपार्थो जिघांसन्त:
>   क्रोधसम्मुर्छतौजस || 25||
>
> Somebody was holding the mechanism which were propelling balls made
>   up of iron (handguns ,cannons etc.) and others were equipped with
>   Chakra , Stones and bhusundi. Angrily they approached towards Shree
>   Krishna and wanted to kill both.

And here is [**Sacred Text**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01230.htm) translation of above verse.

> iron balls and bullets, and catapults for propelling huge stones, and
>   rockets,  See p. 443

Comment: shataghni is a missile, Pushkar. Not necessarily a cannon.

Comment: @moonstar Yes , One or two sources are saying that it's a missile , but most of the sources i have linked are saying that it's a cannon.